# Jquery .load() rewrites whole page

Tags: jquery, html, load

I'm trying to have a div with dynamic content in it by using JQuery's .load() but none of the suggested solutions I found seems to work like I want.

Currently, I have the following setup:

t1.html (main page)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="ts1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                init_s();
            });        
        </script>
        <div>
            <div id="dt1"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

t3.php (content that is supposed to be loaded)

```
<?php
    echo '<div id="dt1"><script>document.write(Date());</script></div>'; 
?>
```

---

ts1.js (file containt the script)

```
function init_s()
{
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#dt1").load('t3.php');
    }, 2000);
};
```

---

but I just don't seem to get it working. After loading the page, it executes the command and replaces the document body completely.

I also tried other approaches like

```
$("#dt1").load('t3.php #dt1>*','');
```

and

```
$("#dt1").load('t3.php #dt1');
```

Since the entire body is now replaced by the contents of the dt1 in t3.php, the div itself is missing and therefore no updates are following.

I thought I maybe need to wrap another div around the div and such but I'm not getting rid of the "replace whole body" behaviour whatsoever, leading to only a single update that replaces the whole body instead of the contents of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `document.write` does.

If you run it in a document which is in a closed state (i.e. which has already loaded (which `t1.html` has)), it will implicitly call `document.open` and erase the existing document.

Use DOM manipulation instead of `document.write`.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I'm kind of lacking the idea how to get the result, though. Is there an elegant approach or am I just going to try and load the t3.php into a var and extract the data and then use replacewith?That seems very unhandy to me

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's the best to not use javascript to markup the other page at all. 
Got a working solution by relying on plain PHP in the t3.php.

the call in ts1.js stays the same

```
function (){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#dt1").load('t3.php');
    }, 2000);
};
```

for t3.php I used the following to test if it's working as intended

```
<?php
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $date; 
?>
```

removing document.write() like Quentin suggested solves the override problem, instead using regular PHP echos results in returning the content to the DIV like expected and doesn't require DOM manipulation which is the easiest approach for my project so far.